# Kernel and linear transformations for vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $W\leqslant V,\;\dim W\lt\infty$ and $T\in\mathcal L(W)$.

My task is to prove that,

$$\ker(T)+W=W \text{ and }\dim Im(T(W))+\dim(Ker(T)\cap W)=\dim(W)$$

I start first to prove that, $T(W)$ is vector subspace of $V$ then how shall i continue this task.

Answer (score 0):

Just forget about $V$.

Observe $\ker(T)\leqslant W$ this you can easily see from definition of $\ker T$ and it is always true. In general, it has nothing to do with finite dimension.

Also $\ker(T)\cap W=W \implies \dim(W)=\dim(\ker(T)\cap W)$

Hence  $\ker(T)+W=W$ and it implies

And the next thing follows from Rank-Nulity theorem
$\dim(T(W))+\dim(\ker(T)\cap W)=\dim(W)$

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a proof of the rank-nullity theorem.

**Proposition**

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space where $\dim V = n$. If $T:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear operator, then the following relation holds
>   \begin{align*}
> \dim V = \dim\ker(T) + \dim\text{Im}(T)
> \end{align*}

**Proof**

Since $\ker(T)$ is a linear subspace of $V$, we can extend its basis $\mathcal{B} = \{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{m}\}$ to a basis of the whole vector space $\mathcal{B}_{V} = \{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}\}$.

On the other hand, $w\in\text{Im}(T)$ iff $w = T(v)$ for some $v = a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2} + \ldots + a_{n}v_{n}\in V$. More precisely
\begin{align*}
w\in\text{Im}(T) \Longrightarrow w & = T(a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2} + \ldots + a_{n}v_{n})\\\\
& = a_{1}T(v_{1}) + a_{2}T(v_{2}) + \ldots + a_{n}T(v_{n})\\\\
& = a_{m+1}T(v_{m+1}) + a_{m+2}T(v_{m+2}) + \ldots + a_{n}T(v_{n})
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that $\{T(v_{m+1}),T(v_{m+2}),\ldots,T(v_{n})\}$ spans $\text{Im}(T)$. It remains to prove it is LI.

Indeed, one has that
\begin{align*}
0 & =\alpha_{m+1}T(v_{m+1}) + \alpha_{m+2}T(v_{m+2}) + \ldots + \alpha_{n}T(v_{n})\\\\
& = T(\alpha_{m+1}v_{m+1} + \alpha_{m+2}v_{m+2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}v_{n}) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \alpha_{m+1}v_{m+1} + \alpha_{m+2}v_{m+2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}v_{n} = \beta_{1}v_{1} + \beta_{2}v_{2} + \ldots + \beta_{m}v_{m}\\\\
& \Rightarrow \alpha_{m+1}v_{m+1} + \alpha_{m+2}v_{m+2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}v_{n} - \beta_{1}v_{1} - \beta_{2}v_{2} - \ldots - \beta_{m}v_{m} = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \beta_{1} = \beta_{2} = \ldots = \beta_{m} = \alpha_{m+1} = \alpha_{m+2} = \ldots = \alpha_{n} = 0
 \end{align*}
thence it results that $\{T(v_{m+1}),T(v_{m+2}),\ldots,T(v_{n})\}$ is LI, and we are done.